# Cryostasis alternatives.

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

What other ways are there to save a human for a very long time. I know only about cryostasis. Let's say we have a spaceship traveling several hundred light years to a distant galaxy.

Comment: Find a tesseract located somewhere near a black hole and do remember that from now on don't replace any non-working watch :)

Comment: @user6760  I'm not Marvel.

Comment: @SovereignSun - That's a reference to [*Interstellar*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/) actually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really want to go to a *distant* galaxy you should first realize the *nearest* (Andromeda) is about 2.5 *million* light years.

If You really want to travel that far (and get there before your ship falls apart) I think the best is "just" to exploit Lorentz time contraction.

Have your spaceship to travel very near to light speed (say 0.99c) so that the crew would travel ~7.3 light-years in a single (subjective) year.

Going even closer to light speed effect would be more relevant (at 0.999c in a single year spaceship would travel more than 22.6 light-years).

At that speed you really need to start paying attention to the road ahead, so having an active crew (not in hibernation) may be actually useful.

Comment: That's helpful. I was thinking of worm holes or vortexes at first, but it's too crazy.

Comment: Wait, when travelling with speed 0.99c isn't the speed 9.9 lightyears in a year? And when 0.999c the speed must be ~31.6 LY.

Comment: @rus9384 I'd reject 0.99c -> 9.9 lightyears/year as too much of a coincidence to not be misremembered if I saw it from an untrusted source. But regardless it doesn't scale linearly like that.

Comment: Getting up to those speeds might be tricky, but it's useful to remember that travelling at the speed of light (1c) implies that _time does not pass_.  Just get close enough, and you can make the trip last as long (or short) as you need.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, who said linear? 0.99/sqrt(1-0.99)=0.99/sqrt(0.01)=0.99/0.1=0.99*10

Comment: Worth remembering that from the frame of reference of the ship, it simply never stops accelerating...

Comment: "At that speed you really need to start paying attention to the road ahead, so having an active crew (not in hibernation) may be actually useful." What about an autonomous spacecraft though?

Comment: @rus9384 By that logic, 0.9999c means 99.99 lightyears / year, and 0.999c means... that's self-consistent. Sorry for the accusation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, that's just a coincidence. Formula is correct and gives ~31.6 LY/Y relative speed when real speed is 0.999c.

Comment: What I'm interested in is how the crew would deal with meteors when flying **that** fast?

Comment: @rus9384: They wouldn't. Even intergalactic dust densities would cause problems at those kinds of speeds. Meteors would turn the ship into a very fast moving smear of plasma.

Answer (score 10):

Digitize and replicate.

Why waste space for storage and preservation on a long journey when you can digitize the occupants and replicate them upon arrival. Any sort of stasis system is going to be complex and require ongoing maintenance power. The advantage of digitizing and replicating the passengers is that all the complex machinery can be left in a powered off state for the journey.

Comment: That's not good. You replicate a different being.

Comment: @SovereignSun How so?

Comment: @SovereignSun Are you an [engineer](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=1879) by chance?

Comment: This might work from a cloning mindset. You have your system establish an automated colony, and then the system automatically produces fully grown clones to populate it. Its entirely up to you if you want the clones to remember their original selves (ideal), but I have read some book where they have made workers by repeatedly cloning the same 2 people until you have thousands of the same 2 bodies, all with completely different memories. Just an interesting thought I had on this idea.

Comment: @SovereignSun If you store enough information, you would have a result that was identical to the original. The only problem would be if you JPEG-compressed the people. (Remember: you _are_ the author so _you_ can decide.)

Comment: Relevant WaitButWhy: [What makes you you?](https://waitbutwhy.com/2014/12/what-makes-you-you.html)

Comment: @Siguza Discerning travelers make sure their digitizers and replicators carry a youness guarantor module.

Comment: @sphennings et. al, If I were to digitize myself, leave my original alive, then create a duplicate, I would have two independent people.  True, they would be very similar (but would diverge over time), but the duplicate is a different person with his own will, perception, and cognition. The only difference between the two propositions is that in the answer, I kill the original me so the duplicate me doesn't notice he's a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewNeely You only think that because your brain gives you the illusion of self, and you can't help feeling that you are the "real" you, and the copy is some other person. If you boil it down to just the physics, there is no such thing as a "person", just a collection of atoms organized in a particular way. Asking which is "you" and which is the "copy" is a meaningless question. At the moment of duplication, both are identical, and neither one is any more valid than the other.

Comment: @JBentley Those who are religious wouldn't like this idea. I'm nit but I still wouldn't like to be digitized and then replicated. I'm birn and I should die some time, it's how nature has made things go with humans. It should stay so forever.

Comment: @JBentley, since human society is predicated on the illusions of self and personhood, it matters.  Humans cannot base society otherwise.  If I were to hack a table apart, people may think me strange.  If I hack apart my wife, they think me evil and imprison me (or worse.)  You cannot live by the philosoply you espouse, neither can any society.

Answer (score 9):

**Stasis Field**

In the ring world books some ships would carry a singularity device. In case of a drastic deceleration (hitting a planet) the cockpit is enveloped in a stasis field.

Inside this field time stand still, avoiding any aging or damage to the material inside.

Comment: +1 Good. Any other possible ways?

Answer (score 5):

Another way might be to genetically engineer an immortal human.

Lobsters are thought to be [biologically immortal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality), which means they won't die unless they are killed.

It would be challenging, but at least it's not theoretically impossible.

Comment: Biohacking is the most interesting solution by far. If you can figure out how to make more junk DNA - I think to protect chromosomes from making bad copies, but I'm not sure about that - then you essentially solve the problem of humans ageing. You can just also regularly inject humans with white bloodcells and other genetic material that would need to be replenished too.

Comment: @steve Curing aging is [far more complicated than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategies_for_Engineered_Negligible_Senescence), to the point where many mainstream scientists don't even consider it feasible. The aspects you identified are not the only problems to be solved.

Comment: @JBentley many mainstream scientists think many things, but they're not building this man's world.

Comment: @Steve You misunderstand. I'm not saying he should rule out this idea because it's technically challenging. I'm saying he should be aware of *what* makes it technically challenging, so that he can decide how detailed / realistic to be.

Comment: @JBentley Ah I understand now. That's a good point to raise, my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The Mi-Go have been helping humans travel to Yuggoth for a long time!  Their method (from Lovecraft's [The Whisperer in Darkness](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/wid.aspx)):

> There was a harmless way to extract a brain, and a way to keep the
>   organic residue alive during its absence. The bare, compact cerebral
>   matter was then immersed in an occasionally replenished fluid within
>   an ether-tight cylinder of a metal mined in Yuggoth, certain
>   electrodes reaching through and connecting at will with elaborate
>   instruments capable of duplicating the three vital faculties of sight,
>   hearing, and speech. For the winged fungus-beings to carry the
>   brain-cylinders intact through space was an easy matter. Then, on
>   every planet covered by their civilisation, they would find plenty of
>   adjustable faculty-instruments capable of being connected with the
>   encased brains; so that after a little fitting these travelling
>   intelligences could be given a full sensory and articulate life—albeit
>   a bodiless and mechanical one—at each stage of their journeying
>   through and beyond the space-time continuum. It was as simple as
>   carrying a phonograph record about and playing it wherever a
>   phonograph of the corresponding make exists.

No doubt the human brain in its case is protected from free radical damage and constant degradation caused by movements of the body - and so is practically ageless.  Encased brains can be connected to temporary artificial bodies as needed for various purposes - humanoid or otherwise.  Much of the time these individuals occupy themselves in virtual landscapes, freed from the constraints of the physical.

[image: encased brain]
from https://lovecraftianscience.wordpress.com/tag/the-whisperer-in-darkness/

Answer (score 2):

**[Quantum Entanglements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement)**

Recently in the field of quantum physics, the plausibility of teleportation was elevated with the discovery of Quantum Entanglements.

With this science in mind, you could either teleport your human or save his state. Using a Quantum computer and one heck of a memory device you could save the entire atomic state and structure of a human body off into some storage. Upon arriving just reassemble the entanglements. This would preserve the electrical state of the brain though you would inevitably raise questions like:

- What do you do with the original?
- What does this mean for the human soul?

Answer (score 1):

Cryostatis Pro: we (of september 14 of 2017) are doing this every single day, at least in first world countries. So the techonolgy already exists.

Con: the frozen water expands bursting cells open thus killing the thing you want to perserve.

May i introduce you to the Medical Nanobots. **tiny little robots,** nanobots (in fiction at least) serve many different roles. This specific role is to make sure the chemical-horomal balance of humans in statis allows them to "Crash Wake" (aka OMG THE SHIP IS FALLING APART BECAUSE REASONS! WAKE UP NOOOWWW!) in emergences.

The nanobots will of course make sure your passengers get enough stuff to survive the journey and may double as DNA Repair Systems for radiation treatment. (Example: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7401A3k7OYc)

Sure the end product may not be Genetically human. But it got them there didn't it? Also this allows for a sub plot on what it means to be human.